# Complex data merge in Adobe InDesign for business cards

Tags: csv, adobe-indesign, mailmerge

I have a spreadsheet of people's info for business cards including name, title, phone, mobile and email that I want to use as the input file for an InDesign data merge. The phone, mobile and email lines are prepended with "T", "M" and "E", respectively. Example:

```
[NAME]
[TITLE]

T [PHONE_NUMBER]
M [MOBILE_NUMBER]
E [EMAIL_ADDRESS]
```

The problem is that some people don't have a value for every field (e.g. many don't have a value for mobile) and this makes a data merge more complicated; if a row doesn't have a value for a particular field, not only does the value need to not show (which I have managed to do — data merge can hide the line if the value is omitted as long as it's the only thing on that line) but the letter prepended to the line needs to not show too.

Is it possible and, if so, how?

Comment: Is this related in any way to *programming*, or is it just 'how to do this task with Adobe InDesign'? If the latter, it may better be asked on [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) (although it is not a *design* question) or on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: It's more of a technical productivity question, but you're right. Moved to Graphic Design!

Answer (score 0):

Moved to https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42745/complex-data-merge-in-adobe-indesign-for-business-cards

*As Jongware correctly pointed out, this is a question for GD, not SO.*